# Nested HierarchicalDataTemplate - improvement

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, hierarchicaldatatemplate

Is any way to do this more clearly (auto-deeply in ObservableCollection)? If I had more 'Childs', it is getting annoying.

In my class i have collection:

> public ObservableCollection ObservableChildNodes { get; set; }

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="ChildChildChildChildNodeTemplate">
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="ChildChildChildNodeTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ObservableChildNodes}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ChildChildChildChildNodeTemplate}">
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="ChildChildNodeTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ObservableChildNodes}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ChildChildChildNodeTemplate}">
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="ChildNodeTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ObservableChildNodes}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ChildChildNodeTemplate}">
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="RootNodeTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ObservableChildNodes}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ChildNodeTemplate}">
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" FontWeight="Bold" />
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, simply remove the `ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ChildChildNodeTemplate}"`

you only need the first and second layer if you want to display the first layer differently.

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="ChildNodeTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ObservableChildNodes}">
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="RootNodeTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ObservableChildNodes}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ChildNodeTemplate}">
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" FontWeight="Bold" />
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```